# Check progress for Upload (Google GMail API for Android)

Tags: android, api, gmail, listener, progress

I'm getting frustrated trying to get information about the progress of my asynctask while inserting a mail through Gmail Api for Android.

I'm trying to use the MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener but the problem is that i just get null out of the getMediaHttpUploader() method of the insert.

I think i'm missing something big in the middle to get the expected response out of the getMediaHttpUploader...

This is my code:

```
private class TareaGestionEnvioMails extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Message> {
    @Override
    protected Message doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            if (mensaje != null) {
                String user = "me";

                Gmail.Users.Messages.Insert insert = servicioGmail.users().messages().insert(user, mensaje);
                MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
                //getMediaHttpUploader returns me null value :(
                uploader.setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
                uploader.setChunkSize(1024*256);
                uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener());

                mensaje = insert.execute();
            }
            return mensaje;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mLastError = e;
            cancel(true);
            return null;
        }
    }
...

    private class FileUploadProgressListener implements MediaHttpUploaderProgressListener {

    public FileUploadProgressListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void progressChanged(MediaHttpUploader mediaHttpUploader) throws IOException {
        if (mediaHttpUploader == null) return;
        switch (mediaHttpUploader.getUploadState()) {
            case INITIATION_STARTED:
                pantallaPrincipal.onProgresoEnviarMail(0.0, "INITIATION_STARTED");
                break;
            case INITIATION_COMPLETE:
                pantallaPrincipal.onProgresoEnviarMail(0.0, "INITIATION_COMPLETE");
                break;
            case MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS:
                double percent = mediaHttpUploader.getProgress() * 100;
                pantallaPrincipal.onProgresoEnviarMail(percent, "MEDIA_IN_PROGRESS");
                break;
            case MEDIA_COMPLETE:
                pantallaPrincipal.onProgresoEnviarMail(100.0, "MEDIA_COMPLETE");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks Everyone! This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!!!!

You have to use the three parameter version of the insert() method. I've filled the third parameter with my **MimeMessage** this way:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myMimeMessage.writeTo(baos);
AbstractInputStreamContent mediaContent = new ByteArrayContent("message/rfc822", baos.toByteArray());
Gmail.Users.Messages.Insert insert = servicioGmail.users().messages().insert(user, null, mediaContent);
```

There are two things you have to be aware of:

1) If you keep using the "**Message**" and the "**AbstractInputStreamContent**" parameters both at the same time, you will be happy with little messages... But if you have to upload a message bigger than around 1mb, you will get a horrible 400 Bad_Request exception with a "Request too large" error. So, leave the Message parameter null.

2) Leaving the "Message" parameter null, you can't set the **Label** of the message... so you will have to fill it later using users().messages().**modify** method.

If anyone have a nicer workaround to insert a big mail and it's label at the same time, and having a feedback of the progress, please comment! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, this helped me. Thank you!